# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null what am I doing wrong or missing out on?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a loop that should fetch the `word` and `syllables`, but whenever I do so I get the next error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null

Code where I create the input fields:
In this function my JSON should append `word`:

```
function getWordInput(id, cValue) {
    cValue = cValue || '';
    var wInput = $('<input/>', {
        'class': 'exerciseGetWordInput_' + id + ' form-group form-control ExerciseGetWordInput word',
        'type': 'text',
        'name': 'question_takeAudio_exerciseWord[' + exerciseAudioInput + ']',
        'placeholder': 'Exercise',
        'id': 'exerciseGetWordInput',
        'required': true
    });
    return wInput;
}
```

In this second part my JSON should append `syllables`:

```
// This is the function that creates the syllable inputs.
function getWordPartInput(id, cValue) {
    cValue = cValue || '';
    var wpInput = $('<input/>', {
        'class': 'form-group form-control syllable syl ' + TT++,
        'type': 'text',
        'value': cValue,
        'placeholder': 'Syllables',
        'name': 'Syllablescounter[' + SyllablesID++ + ']'
    });
    return wpInput;
}
```

How my loop looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('json_files/jsonData_' + ID + '.json', function(json) {

        //loops through the words and fetches them back to the CMS side.
        var exercise = json.main_object.main_object.exercises;


        exercise.forEach((exercise, index) => {
            const word = exercise.word; // should grab the word
            const syls = exercise.syllables; // Grab the syllables array
            const container = document.querySelector(`.word-${index}`); // Get the correct container based on our index(index)
            container.querySelector('.word').value = word; // Assign the word to the first input
            // Foreach syllable
            syls.forEach((syl, i) => {
                container.querySelectorAll('.syl')[i].value = syls; // Assign the syllable to the correct input based on our index(i)
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Not sure if this will be needed, but in case you want to see my JSON:

```
{
   "main_object":{
      "id":"new",
      "getExerciseTitle":"Example",
      "language":"nl_NL",
      "application":"lettergrepen",
      "main_object":{
         "title":"Example",
         "language":"nl_NL",
         "exercises":[
            {
               "word":"Example",
               "syllables":[
                  "Example1",
                  "Example2",
                  "",
                  ""
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      "dataType":"json"
   }
}
```

Comment: `document.querySelector(`.word-${index}`)` is undefined in your case

Comment: and how could I possibly change this so it won't be undefined / null?